# How to load XML from external site periodically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, ajax

On a personal project I'm working on, I have a requirement where I need to save (on disk) a XML feed periodically from an external site, and then parse the XML and render the contents in a particular format.  Parsing the XML and rendering it is no problem - the confusion comes in finding the appropriate way to pole the external site/url store the XML periodically.

I have done a fair amount of research, but I've ended up even more stumped.  My initial thoughts were to create a service that poles the external site, and retrieve and store the XML at prescribed intervals.  I've not created a service before, so a) I'm not really sure where to start, and b) I'll be hosting the site through a hosting provider and I'm not sure that this a viable option?

The SO thread [writing a service to periodically retrieve XML and send SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742154/writing-a-service-to-periodically-retrieve-xml-and-send-sms) seems to do exactly what I need, but I don't entirely understand the proposed solution.

I also found [an article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25218/Fast-Scalable-Streaming-AJAX-Proxy-continuously-de) on delivering data across domains using an AJAX proxy, but this seems overkill for what I need.

Does anyone have any recommmendations on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx) and when you're finished, I would suggest you read the XML via an HTTPWebRequest, instead of trying to download it. I assume you'll be able to do this and write the result to a file? If not, I can expand my answer a bit.

You'll definitely want to create a windows service as their sole purpose is to keep running in the background and periodically do stuff.

Comment: "A windows service is what you want because..."?  The suspense is killing me.  If you could expand that would be great.

Comment: [Ctrl] + [F5] should help.

Comment: @MarkErasmus, because it runs in background, you can configure it to start automatically when Windows starts, it does not have UI so invisible to users. What else would you want?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion - I understand the function of a Windows Service. @JuannStrauss intial post ended with "A windows service is what you want because" and refreshing the browser wasn't updating he post.

Comment: @JuannStrauss, sounds good. I'll be hosting with Azure so I guess I would have to create a worker role instead of a Windows service to achieve this.